# Subtract from first value in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Having numpy array like that:

```
a = np.array([35,2,160,56,120,80,1,1,0,0,1])
```

I want to subtract custom value (for example, 5) from first element of the array. Basically it can be done like:`a[0] - 5`

But how can I apply this result to the initial array and replace the first value with the answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
a[0] -= 5  # use -=
```

This will turn `a` into:

```
>>> a = np.array([35,2,160,56,120,80,1,1,0,0,1])
>>> a[0] -= 5
>>> a
array([ 30,   2, 160,  56, 120,  80,   1,   1,   0,   0,   1])
```

For most operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc.), there is an "inplace" equivalent (`+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, etc.) that will apply that operation with the right operand and store it back.

Note that if you want to subtract *all* elements, you should not use a Python `for` loop, there are more efficient ways for that.