# How to subtract a value from one of value in a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an array from which I need to subtract the a value from one of the value in the array

I followed the suggestion given in this link. But didn't work in my case

My sample code is given below. In this , I wanted to subtract '1' from the second value of array (as mentioned in the function sig2(k).

I have tried as per the below link. But couldn't succeed.

Can some one let me know where am I going wrong

[Subtract from first value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330221/subtract-from-first-value-in-numpy-array)

```
import numpy as np

k = [1,3]
coe = np.array([[k[0],k[1]]])

def sig2(k):
    return k[0] * np.power(lam1,((k[1]=-1)))

print(sig2(k))
```

Comment: `k[1] -= 1` The '-' sign needs to be there before '='. `k[1] = -1` assigns -1 to 2nd value.

Comment: With that settings, Iam getting:  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You want t0 calculate (lam1 ^ k[1]) ? in words, lam1 raise to k[1]. Also, what is the value of lam1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code, is this what you want?

```
import numpy as np

k = [1,3]
coe = np.array([[k[0],k[1]]])
lam1 = 5
def sig2(k):
    k[1] -= 1
    return k[0] * np.power(lam1,(k[1]))

print(sig2(k))
```

Output

```
25
```